# Conda (Anaconda) functionality

Tags: anaconda, conda

I am new to conda and virtualenv and thought to move in with conda.
Whenever I execute this command in cmd, the cursor just stays blinking and nothing is executed:

```
conda create -n sympy-dev-py27 python=2.7 mpmath>=0.19
```

Answer (score 4):

The shell interprets the `>` sign as the start of an i/o redirection.  You can get around this using quoting.  Try

```
conda create -n sympy-dev-py27 python=2.7 "mpmath>=0.19"
```

Comment: He stated using cmd, on plain cmd `''` does not quote the string and `""` should be used.